# Function documented in package downloaded from CRAN but not available when loading the package. Function reverselog_trans from ACSNMineR

Tags: r, cran

I have installed using R studio the package `ACSNMineR`  from CRAN. In the documentation of CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ACSNMineR/ACSNMineR.pdf, it appears a function named `reverselog_trans`, but when I load the package through `library(ACSNMineR)` the function that not appear as define. But the version of both the documentation in CRAN and the installed package is the same 0.16.8.25. Moreover, in the documentation of the installed package, it is the function documented but it is not defined.

I am using R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29), on Linux mint.

Does anybody have a clue on what is going on ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is working as it should be. The `reverselog_trans()` seems to be a "helper function" that is not exported to the NAMESPACE. That means the function is there ([a link to GitHub](https://github.com/cran/ACSNMineR/blob/d36d5838befa92c32194528833c4ce766caf44d7/R/plots.R#L216-L231)) and is used by the package itself, but not exported to the user.

When you use `scale = 'reverselog'` as an option in `represent_enrichment()` it calls `reverselog_trans()` in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I found another package that has the same function define in NAMESPACE: https://rdrr.io/cran/metR/man/reverselog_trans.html